# Java/Scala Swing: Make a component fill all available space in a row

Tags: java, swing, scala, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create a layout with Swing using GridBagLayout.

I want to place a ComboBox besides a Button, where the Button has a constant size, and the ComboBox fills all the available space in the row:

[image: It Should look like this]

However, if I enlarge the window, empty space appears between the ComboBox and the Button:

[image: Sadly, it looks more like this]

How can I layout this form, so that the ComboBox fills all the space, even when the window is resized?

Layout code for the components, in Scala:

```
layout(button) = new Constraints() {
    gridx = 1
    gridy = 0
    anchor = GridBagPanel.Anchor.LineEnd
}

layout(comboBox) = new Constraints() {
    gridx = 0
    gridy = 0
    fill = GridBagPanel.Fill.Horizontal
}

layout(centerPanel) = new Constraints() {
    gridx = 0
    gridy = 1
    weighty = 1
    weightx = 1
    gridwidth = 2
    fill = GridBagPanel.Fill.Both
}
```

Comment: Use a `BorderLayout` for that section of the GUI.  Put the combo. in the `CENTER` and the button in the `LINE_END`.

Comment: Also look into using code point 8594 (rightwards arrow) for the text in the combo..

Comment: Thank you, that's almost perfect. The ComboBox and the Button get centered now, when the window is maximized. Can I make the ComboBox stretch?

Comment: Ah, forgot to set Fill.Horizontal on the parent GridBagLayout. Works now.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but since I'm terrible at using GBL I thought it best to 'stick to what I know' in order to demonstrate the top panel stretching to fill the available width.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BorderLayout` for that section of the GUI. Put the combo. in the `CENTER` and the button in the `LINE_END`.

Like this:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class StretchComboLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
                ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

                JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
                ui.add(controls, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                String s = new String(Character.toChars(8594));
                String[] items = {"Choice: right " + s + " arrow"};
                JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(items);
                controls.add(cb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                controls.add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(
                        JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, 
                        new JTextArea(4,40), 
                        new JTextArea(4,40));

                ui.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Stretch Combo Layout");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(ui);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also the edit to code, where I show what I mean about using the code point for right arrow.